Unexpected error in Range.Formula (Excel)
I would like to store the formula for a chart series in a spreadsheet cell.  The msgbox line works but the last line: /Range("V41") = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula gives me an error.
I will be parsing/modifying the contents of Range("V41").  I would then like to store this revised formula in ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart ").FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula
      Sub ReviseChartDataforEachPlayer()

      ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate

       MsgBox---------- ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula

       Range("V41") = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula

       End Sub

Error Message:
    Error: Run-time error '438'
    Object doesn't support this property or method

